# Windows Registry Monitoring for change using C++

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I have following piece of code that is working on the following steps:

1. Open the RegistryKey using `RegOpenKeyEx`
2. After opening key, Create a event using `CreateEvent`.
3. Using `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` for getting Notification.

The above steps only gives me a notification of change occured but not the information on where the change occured. eg consider following code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    DWORD  dwFilter = REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_NAME|
                     REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
                     REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_SET |
                     REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY;

    HKEY pHresult=0;
    if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\\aaaa",0,KEY_NOTIFY|KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY|KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS|KEY_QUERY_VALUE|KEY_WOW64_64KEY,&pHresult)!=ERROR_SUCCESS){
        std::cout << "FAIL IN OPEN SOFTWARE" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << " OPEN software//aaaa" << std::endl;

    while(1)
    {   
        HANDLE hevent = CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE, TRUE, NULL);
        if(RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(pHresult,TRUE,dwFilter,hevent,TRUE) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            std::cout << "NOTIFICATION FAILED " << std::endl;
        }

        DWORD dwret = WaitForSingleObject(hevent, 2000);    
        if(dwret == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
        {
            std::cout << " TIMEOUT " << std::endl;
        }
        else if (dwret == WAIT_FAILED)
        {
            //
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Change Occured" << std::endl;
        }

        //Sleep(2000);
    }
    RegCloseKey(pHresult);
}
```

In above code, if change is done in `aaaa`, i get `Change Occured`. How do I get the location where the change occured. One way would be using recursion and scanning the whole path. Is there any better way or API for reducing the overhead of recursion way?

Comment: In my opinion, you need to enumerate value to detect the change. It will not tell the change. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Otherwise, there must be some mention in the documentation.

Comment: Recursion and Enumeration will make overhead. Consider changes to be monitored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`. Enumeration for this will take a lot of time.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is there REALLY that many registry writes that it becomes a problem? Have you actually tried it, or are you just hypothetically assuming that "Enumerating all and comparing the keys with a shadow copy will take too long"? How many registry writes are there per second in your system?

Comment: For a registry key with little sub-keys, the approach I'm trying to implement will work. But the user can enter any registry key. Be that `HKLM` or any key under it. Even `HKLM\SOFTWARE` has so much sub-keys that recursion and enumeration will take whole lot of time. How can I achieve the same with little overhead